# How can I reuse a Prolog data structure?

Tags: prolog

I am writing a small program using Prolog. There is a data structure that I want to reuse, so I tried assigning it to a variable:

```
CitizenProfile = voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison).
```

Then I used it like this:

```
state(alabama, [CitizenProfile]).
```

However, I am encountering this error when I compile my file from the console:

```
**[No permission to modify static_procedure `(=)/2'][1]**
==
```

I even tried declaring the equal sign dynamic, but that didn't solve anything. :(

```
:- dynamic (=)/2.
```

Comment: This is Prolog. `voter_profile(citizen, not_in_prison)` does not, in fact, return a result value of any sort. It is a query that will match if the relation `voter_profile` holds for the atoms `citizen` and `not_in_prison`.

Comment: It would also help if you showed more code since what you briefly showed in your problem statement doesn't generate that specific error.

Comment: @mbratch I assure you that it does. Add the first line to a .pl file and load it from the Swipl console.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry @picardo, I was doing it at the command line. In that form, not within the logic of a predicate, it is seen as a redefinition of `=` which could also be written, `=(CitizenProfile, voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison)).` You can't redefine a built-in predicate even with `dynamic`. `dynamic` is used to allow dynamic redefinition or assertion of your own clauses/predicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is that it looks to Prolog like you're trying to do this:

```
=(CitizenProfile, voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison)).
```

This looks just like any other fact definition. `=/2` could just as easily be `foobar/2`:

```
foobar(CitizenProfile, voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison)).
```

Now, if we were in the middle of some rule body, this might be a legitimate way to establish a variable binding. Then everything would be culminating in this:

```
foo :- ...,
    CitizenProfile = voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison),
    state(alabama, [CitizenProfile]).
```

That would be the same as saying this:

```
foo :- ...,
    state(alabama, [voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison)]).
```

If this expansion is what you're trying to accomplish, there is unfortunately no way to create shorthand in a fact database like this. You could, as @hardmath says, use `assertz/1` to accomplish it, which would look like this:

```
make_database :-
    CitizenProfile = voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison),
    assertz(state(alabama, [CitizenProfile])).
```

This would be kind of sketchy behavior though, because you're putting static information into the dynamic store. In my experience, one doesn't usually want to build up large structures in the database. It's usually cleaner and easier to build several relations and "join" across them in a relational manner. I'm not sure what all you're going to want here, so this is just a sketch, but this is kind of what I'd expect to see:

```
voter_profile(voter1, alabama,    citizen, not_in_prison).
voter_profile(voter2, alabama,    citizen, in_prison).
voter_profile(voter3, new_mexico, citizen, not_in_prison).
```

rather than what I presume you'd be building (eventually), which I picture more like this:

```
 state(alabama,   [voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison), voter_profile(citizen, in_prison)]).
 state(new_mexico,[voter_profile(citizen,not_in_prison)]).
```

The temptation to create a bunch of lists is understandable, but Prolog's database can't really help you with processing them. You'll wind up resorting to a lot of `member/2` and O(N) searching which will add up to pretty bad performance. By default, Prolog will index on the first argument, but each implementation defines some indexing declarations you can use to make it index the second or Nth arguments in addition or instead. You can then use `bagof/3` or `findall/3` to reconstitute the lists if you need all the results.

Comment: Thank you for this incredibly helpful answer. You put your finger on my rookie mistake. I am still thinking imperatively! It's so hard to wean away form the OO mindset. So thanks again, and please enjoy the rest of your week.

Comment: @picardo It is hard, but I hope you'll keep at it, and continue to ask questions here on S.O. We all love to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is to define a dynamic predicate `voter_profile/2` and `assertz` new facts "dynamically" to be remembered by that predicate store (the *clause* database).  I say "probably" because you haven't made it clear how a state (e.g. Alabama) should be related to a particular citizen profile.

See [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=db) for the SWI-Prolog builtin `assertz/1` documentation and much more on database mechanisms of SWI-Prolog.